# Create Microstrategy Metrics without using gui

Tags: microstrategy

I'm creating a report that will have something like 200 metrics in it.  I'm wondering if it's possible to create the metrics without having to go through the gui steps of importing a schema object, then creating a fact, then creating a metric from the fact.

Is it possible to use a custom sql query as the data source for a report, and will that automatically create the metrics without requiring them to be created in the gui step?

In general is there a way to create attributes, facts, metrics without using the gui?  Like is there a way to modify the code, so I could just copy and paste code for a bunch of metrics at one time?  Or is there a way to bulk create metrics in microstrategy?

Answer (score 1):

You can bulk create metrics using Command Manager if you have the appropriate [expression.](http://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/10.5/CommandManager/WebHelp/Lang_1033/content/html/cm_syntax_examples/metric_expression_syntax_simple_metrics.htm)

However if you wish to use SQL, then your best bet is to create a Freeform SQL report and define the SQL for the entire report. You can’t define the SQL for a metric since the SQL generated from that metric depends on definition of the report.

You can reference [this guide from MicroStrategy on how to create a Freeform SQL report.](https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/10.7/ReportDesigner/WebHelp/Lang_1033/Content/ReportDesigner/creating_a_freeform_sql_report.htm)